# Unable to create in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets-api

I was trying google APIs to create a new sheet but I am unable to achieve the goal

the error I am getting is

> Invalid spreadsheet. spreadsheet: This user did not create this id.

so I thought I am doing something wrong did some research I got this link (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) and tried it here (Try it! button) it gives the same error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid spreadsheet.spreadsheetId: This user did not create this id.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I thought that in your question when you provide the detailed request and the request body for correctly replicating your issue, it will help users think of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just performing the following request will create a spreadsheet:

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets
```

No need to pass something in the body. The documentation is a bit confusing on that point as it says you should send an instance of Spreadsheet in the request body. But you don't have to.